# How to dynamically add to a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to figure out how to get the following results...

```
var errors;
errors = { username: "username_error", email: "email_error" };
```

...when looping through data in this code:

```
var errors = {}
$.each(data,function(k,v)
{
   errors[k] = v; // doesn't seem to work
});
```

It does produce an object yet in a different format.

EDIT: console log.

Expected results:

```
Object
email: "email_error"
username: "username_error"
__proto__: Object
 edit:25
Object
__proto__: Object
```

Generated results:

```
Object
email: Array[1]
0: "email_error"
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
username: Array[1]
0: "username_error"
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: data is a JSON object. k and v are strings.

Comment: ... Right.  Can you do a console.log(data) and put that here?

Comment: Are you sure the objects in data aren't arrays?

Comment: STILL don't know what the hell is in data!  PLEASE do a `console.log(data)`.  It will help us eliminate the easy fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the results you posted with the log output, it seems the objects in `data` are arrays. Try replacing the assignment with this:

```
errors[k] = v.length>0 ? v[0] : ""
```

Comment: indeed it was an array. v[0] worked. I hate mjself for literally wasting hours on this :) thank you.

Comment: all you had to do was a `console.log(data)`, the console is your friend, use it...

Comment: the funny thing is... I was using it but I was just too blind to notice the array type.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var errors = {}
$.each(data,function(k,v)
{
   errors[k] = v[0];

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Jqk/2/).